# TSQL Clarification

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have the following line in a select statement:

```
cast (row_number( ) OVER ( ORDER BY cs.OrgId ) AS int) AS rowId
```

Could someone please confirm if I am understanding this right?

Order by Org Id and create a new column rowId as an int holding a value of the orgid position in the order?

Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, it orders the whole resultset by `OrgId`, and the result it's a sequential number starting from 1, with no duplicates. Then it's casting it as an `INT`  since the result of `ROW_NUMBER` is a `BIGINT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not exact what you say. The function `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [order])` returns a value that represents the position that the row would occupy if the rows were ordered by the specified order.

This nuance means several things:

- you can get different row numbers (or other rank), using different orders (and rank functions)
- you can order the final result set by any other criterion, different to the one of the `row_number()` function
- you can use the result of the `row_number()` (or any other window function) to filter, group by or whatever you want to do with it

The `cast` part only converts from `BIGINT` to `INT`.

And the "creates a new column" depends on where you use the window function. For example you can use it in the `where` clause, in which case it doesn't create a new column at all.

You can read the [documentation on OVER clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) which has full explanations, and several samples. See also the [ranking functions docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).